# How to calculate Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) with Krylov subspace methods?

Tags: optimization, reference-request, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

**Background** : I have used Krylov subspace methods for a rather long time now, designing algorithms with the help of posing and solving mostly sparse matrix*vector 2-norm minimization problems.

One thing I have not done so far is to perform Singular Value Decomposition (SVD). It is defined for any matrix $\bf A$, to find $\bf U,V,\Sigma$  so that :

$${\bf A = U\Sigma V}^*$$ where $\bf U,V$ are orthonormal and $\bf \Sigma$ is diagonal with exclusively non-negative real entries and ${\bf M}^*$ means conjugate transpose of $\bf M$.

How could this be achieved? Not only answers describing how but also references to works, articles, even blogs will be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me sketch the outline of a method, using the same technique I've addressed in another answer [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35626/implementation-of-sparse-matrix-svd-for-gpu/35630#35630). The key observation is that an SVD of $A$ can readily obtained from an *eigenvalue computation* of the related matrix

$$
B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & A \\ A^* & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

In fact the nonzero eigenvalues of $B$ are precisely $\pm$ the nonzero singular values of $A$ with eigenvectors

$$
B \begin{bmatrix} u \\ \pm v\end{bmatrix} = \pm \sigma \begin{bmatrix} u \\ \pm v\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $u$ and $v$ are right and left singular vectors of $A$! One can thus adapt any Krylov subspace method for the symmetric eigenvalue problem (e.g. Lanczos) to compute an SVD by applying this method to $B$ and recovering from it a (full or partial) SVD of $A$.

In fact, you don't even have to write the matrix $B$ down. All a Kyrlov subspace method for a symmetric eigenvalue problem requires is the ability to compute products of the form $x \mapsto Bx$. But this can be done by using subroutines to multiply by $A$ and $A^*$ by using the fact that

$$
B\begin{bmatrix} y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} Az \\ A^*y \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Note that multiplying by $A^*$ is absolutely essential. Any reasonable Krylov subspace method for the SVD must utilize both multiplications with $A$ and $A^*$. To see why, consider the simple case when $A = uv^*$ for vectors $u$ and $v$.Then it is very difficult to determine $v$ in $A=uv^*$ by only multiplications with $A$. This is because, once you've figured out $u$, each product $Ax = (v^*x)u$ with only tells you $v^*x$. To completely determine $v$ from inner products with other vectors $x$, you'll need many many inner products (as many as the size of $v$).

Alternately, you could use Krylov subspace methods on $A^*A = V\Sigma^2 V^*$ and $AA^* = U\Sigma^2 U^*$. This has the disadvantage of needing to compute two matvecs every iteration and needing to solve two separate problems, one for $U$ and one for $V$, but the problem does become positive semidefinite, which may be useful.

Comment: I have designed my own eigenvalue-eigenvector solver with Krylov methods so this is actually very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: If you solve $A^TA$ to obtain $V$ and $\Sigma$, you can get $U$ for "free" by $U = A V \Sigma^{-1}$, and similarly to obtain $U$ from $AA^T$. In the case that the dimensions of $A$ are very different, it may be advantageous to compute the smaller of $A^TA$ and $AA^T$, and then find the corresponding eigendecomposition. Of course, such matrices are more poorly conditioned that the $B$ given in this solution, so there are also considerations there.

Comment: @tch Thanks for your correction and all very good points! If one uses black boxes to compute the actions of $A$ and it’s (conjugate) transpose, then the operation count to compute the action of $AA^\top$, $A^\top A$, and $B$ are all the same, but the storage costs can be much lower for the smaller of $AA^\top$ and $A^\top A$ if $A$ has two very differently sized dimensions. Unless one is very memory constrained or really wants a positive semidefinite matrix, my preference is for the $B$ matrix because of conditioning reasons as you mentioned, but others might have a different perspective.

Comment: Another thought I had regarding using $A^\top A$ is that if one uses a numerically stable orthogonalization method, the columns of $V$ will be numerical orthogonally but the columns of $U = AV\Sigma^{-1}$ may not be numerically orthogonal I believe, particularly if $A$ is ill-conditioned. Again, everything in scientific computing is context-dependent, but something that could possibly be relevant.